# Filter Sharepoint 2010 List with Duplicate Items

Tags: list, filter

I have a list that is being used for document control. The list contains multiple items with the same Title as well as other columns. It also contains a manual revision column I would like to display only the record with the highest value for each similar title. (see below)

*Default list view:*

Title       Rev      DOC ID

1. Item 1      0        123456
2. Item 1      1        123456
3. Item 1      2        123456

*Latest Version View:*

Title      Rev      DOC ID

1. Item 1     2        123456

I hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is simple lines you would need to:

1. Use filter to show ONLY those titles (or group by Title to get all various "clusters")
2. Order descendant by the Column for which you Seek the Maximum
3. Put an Item Limit of 1.

The only question I see open is related to the Clustering (e.g. if you are trying to make the solution reusable). In that situation, i could imagine that some XSLT based conditions in a customized DataForm/XSLTView could work - By example, when calculating groups, in the XSLT there is a condition to check if items are the same. in that place you could use a Variable to compare 2 subsequent items (by using your dedicated column for the Max Version) and the bigger one will be marked visible, while the other no > a sort of bubble-sort!